# Thread Cond. Is this correct C++ way?

Tags: multithreading

Just wanted to see if this is the right way of doing things:

```
Thread A {
    pthread_lock_mutex(&mutex);
    while(flag_set())
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    read_file();
    pthread_unlock_mutex(&mutex);
}

Thread B{
    pthread_cond_signal( &cond );
}
```

Sorry, I am quite new to threading.

Comment: Is this C/C++??? I don't understand what you mean by 'lock itself'. Can you elaborate on the desired behavior while a thread is busy? I'm assuming by *I only want the first thread to perform this time consuming task when user his enter*, that you are using an event handler which will then start an asynchronous task??? I believe the short answer is 'no' - but you can tell a thread to sleep (.net).

Comment: You could use a blocking queue and do a blocking `dequeue()` waiting for some other thread to `enqueue()`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve you goal by using another construct -- e.g. [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) or [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). Below are C# examples for both:

```
var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

new Timer(o => resetEvent.Set(), null, 1, 500); // Set() is called in another thread
                                                // it unblocks main thread

resetEvent.Reset(); // main thread will be blocked in WaitOne() method

while (true)
{
    resetEvent.WaitOne(); // this waits until event is set
    resetEvent.Reset(); // immediatelly reset it back
    // do something

}
```

.....

```
var resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

new Timer(o => resetEvent.Set(), null, 1, 500); // this is called in another thread

resetEvent.Reset();

while (true)
{
    resetEvent.WaitOne();
    // do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Monitor.WAit and Monitor.Pulse

```
    static readonly object _locker = new object();

    static void Main()
    {
      new thread (work1).start();

       new thread (work2).start();

     }

     Static void work1()
     {
         console.writeline("work1 started");
         lock(_locker)
           Monitor.Wait(_locker);   //here we block the first thread until its signaled from the second thread

        console.writeline("work1 wake up");
     }

     static void work2()
     {
           console.writeline("work2 will a wake work1");
           console.readline();
           lock(_locker)
            {
                Monitor.pulse(_locker);    //tell the first thread to continue working
            }
      }
```